# It's not printing what I desire

Tags: c++

I want my code to print "your car is parked in section A" when I enter any number from 0 to 9. It's taking input, but the program terminates without going into the if condition (I think)

```
{  
    int value=0;
    cout<<"Enter car serial number"<<endl;
    cin>>value;
    if(value >= 48 && value <= 57)
    {
        cout<<"your car is parked in section Z"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "0 to 9"  vs `if(value >= 48 && value <= 57)` ... dont you see the difference?

Comment: If the input variable is an `int`, there is no need to compare with ASCII values.

Comment: 48 and 57 are the ascii codes for 0 and 9 respectively. That said this comparison would only work *if* your system uses ascii encoding (not guaranteed) and you were comparing to a char. But even then its confusing. if (value >= '0' && value <= '9') would be *much* clearer (again this if is for comparing to a char). By storing it in an int variable you can check 0 & 9 directly.

Comment: Prefer to use character constants when comparing *characters*.  For example: `if (value < '0' && value <= '9')`.  This makes your code easier to read and debug as well as more portable (some platforms may use encodings other than ASCII).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you confuse getting an int and getting a character

having

> ```
> int value
> ...
> cin >> value;
> ```

you read an *int*, so the input 2 set *value* with the value 2, not with the (ascii) code of the character '2', of course if the input is 123 *value* i set with 123 etc

so of course

> ```
>  if(value >= 48 && value <= 57)
> ```

is not true except of you enter a value between 48 and 57

Doing

```
 char c;

 cin >> c;
```

that time if you enter 2 *c* will be set with '2' so 50 in ascii

---

> I want my code to print "your car is parked in section A" when I enter any number from 0 to 9.

I suppose 0 indicates A, 1 indicates B etc rather than always A

you can do for instance :

```
{  
    int value=0;
    cout<<"Enter car serial number"<<endl;
    cin>>value;
    if(value >= 0 && value <= 9)
    {
        cout<<"your car is parked in section " << *("ABCDEFGHIJ" + value) << endl; // makes no assumption concerning the alpha codes
    }
}
```

but to check the input is a valid integer is better :

```
{  
    int value=0;
    cout<<"Enter car serial number"<<endl;
    if (!(cin>>value))
    {
       cerr << "invalid input" << endl;

       cin.clear(); // raz error

       string s;

       if (! (cin >> s)) // fluxh input
         ..EOF do what you want...
    }
    else if(value >= 0 && value <= 9)
    {
        cout<<"your car is parked in section " << *("ABCDEFGHIJ" + value) << endl; // makes no assumption concerning the alpha codes
    }
    else
        cerr << "invalid serial number" << endl
}
```

---

From your remark :

> I want my code to print "your car is in section "this" where "this" can be A,B or C depending on the serial number of the car. if it's 1-10, then it should be in section A. if it's in 11-20 then in section B.

```
{  
    int value=0;
    cout<<"Enter car serial number"<<endl;
    if (!(cin>>value))
    {
       cerr << "invalid input" << endl;

       cin.clear(); // raz error

       string s;

       if (! (cin >> s)) // fluxh input
         ..EOF do what you want...
    }
    else if(value >= 1 && value <= 260)
    {
        cout<<"your car is parked in section " << *("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + (value-1)/10) << endl; // makes no assumption concerning the alpha codes
    }
    else
        cerr << "invalid serial number" << endl
}
```

Example :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
  for (;;) {
    int value=0;
    cout<<"Enter car serial number"<<endl;
    if (!(cin>>value))
    {
       cerr << "invalid input" << endl;

       cin.clear(); // raz error

       string s;

       if (! (cin >> s)) // fluxh input
         return -1; // ..EOF do what you want...
    }
    else if(value >= 1 && value <= 260)
    {
        cout<<"your car is parked in section " << *("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + (value-1)/10) << endl; // makes no assumption concerning the alpha codes
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cerr << "invalid serial number" << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
-12
invalid serial number
Enter car serial number
0
invalid serial number
Enter car serial number
a
invalid input
Enter car serial number
1
your car is parked in section A
Enter car serial number
10
your car is parked in section A
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
11
your car is parked in section B
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
54
your car is parked in section F
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
250
your car is parked in section Y
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
251
your car is parked in section Z
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter car serial number
260
your car is parked in section Z
```

Comment: ... and the portable transformation `c - '0'` to yield the digit is fairly idiomatic C++.

Comment: `'A' + value` is not portable and sadly ruins this otherwise good answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba please explain why `c - '0'` is portable but `'0' + c ` is not ;-) probably you read wrongly ;-)

Comment: @bruno, in any encoding supported by C++ (and C for that matter), the characters 0, 1, ..., 9 must be contiguous and in that order. The same cannot be said for the alpha characters.

Comment: `'0' + c` is portable so long as `c` is in the range [0, 9]. It's the `'A' + value` that isn't.

Comment: @Bathsheba out of the fact in 35 years I **never** had a c/c++ compiler/lib where 'B' - 'A' is not 1 etc, please can you give me a link to the C/C++ norm saying 0..9 are contiguous but not A..Z etc ?

Comment: @bruno: By counterexample, look at EBCDIC encoding.

Comment: @Bathsheba you do not answer to my question ^^

Comment: Because it's in the comments section and I have a day job. At least one investment / corporate bank in London has C compiled on machines with EBCDIC encoding.

Comment: @bruno I have one more question. Say I want to use numbers bigger than 9, lets say 10 to 20. Then I cannot use the ascii logic, right? so what do we do there? use numbers like  "if variable <= '10' && variable >= '20' ", do this etc etc... like this?

Comment: @scypx '10' is invalid. Note your question you enter number, not character. If you want more that 9 but enough to indicate A up to Z the test just need to be changed to `if(value >= 0 && value <= 'Z' - 'A')`

Comment: @scypx why do you want to read a integer rather than directly a letter between A and Z ?

Comment: actually I want my code to print "your car is in section "this" where "this" can be A,B or C depending on the serial number of the car. if it's 1-10, then it should be in section A. if it's in 11-20 then in section B. I'm trying to use if else logic but not working. It prints section A even if I enter numbers bigger than 10

Comment: @scypx ah ok, this is not part of the question ;-)  and you question speak about Z, so the limit is C or Z ?

Comment: @scypx I edited to allow from A up to Z, just change 'Z' by the letter you want if it is not Z

Comment: @bruno Z is just a section tag like in car parkings. nothing more :-)

Comment: @scypx I am not sure to understand, but my previous remark works, so if only A and B change 'Z' by 'B' in the code at the end of my answer

Comment: @scypx I added a full program with compilation / executions

Comment: @Bathsheba I edited to remove hypothesis concerning the character code and the fact A..Z are consecutive ;-)

Comment: @scypx I edited again, I missed to remove 1 to the value before to divide by 10, sorry